# Jupyter-notebook theme customization

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have recently installed themes for Notebook from [here](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes)

How can I customize these themes?
For example, while using "monokai" theme, I want to change the background of the notebook to **pure Black.**

Comment: see doc : https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes#set-plotting-style-from-within-notebook

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I am wrong but I dont think you can change the background via the commands provided via the [theme github](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes).

You will have to look for the jupyterthemes/styles/monokai.less file on your computer and change it manually. I am assuming its the following variable that needs to be change.

```
@notebook-bg
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I couldn't find this directory structure in my $HOME. I have only .jupyter and .ipython in home directory. Where should I look for "jupyterthemes" directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

To find the jupyterthemes directory, you can open an IPython console and enter the following commands:

```
In [1]: import jupyterthemes
In [2]: print(jupyterthemes.__file__)
```

From there you should be able to find and modify the stylesheet (see M. Glombek's answer).